# Generating standalone file with QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, standalone, style-manager, print-templates

I need to share a project including all feature including **images**, **styles** and **print settings**.

The user that receive this project should be able to print a paper like the .pdf I generate from my PC.

I work on a server but I need that the shared project works also on a local PC.

Is there a guide to follow?

Comment: What's the difficulty here? You share the QGS project file - which holds the styles and the print settings (except those relating specifically to your printer, which your receiver might not have) - and the data files. Is collecting up all the data files an issue?

Comment: You could use qgis project next to gpkg for all the data. If you want only one file you can use gpkg to store the project. What are your other needs ? Storing image ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is the problem, as other comment said the obvious solution is to share the project and as you can save everything in a geopackage (data, style, svg symbol, and QGIS project) this could be done with a single file (but this solution mean that you share with somebody who has QGIS installed and know enough of it to generate output)